# Trying to set up PSQL and i get this error :

Tags: spring, macos, terminal, psql

I am trying to start a Spring project using a PSQL database.
I have installed PSQL using Homebrew but,

When i run :

brew services start postgresql

I get this error:
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/[myusername]/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.

I am following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@viviennediegoencarnacion/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-e6a5f48ee399

Using a mac which is up to date.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have docker installed ? You can use docker to install postgres in your system.

Answer (score 3):

So my postgres service was started apparently.
Therefore when i was trying to start it again it causes an error.
Fix was to stop it and re run.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This may be a track, but it doesn't happen for me again since I updated to Monterey and running PSQL13

A full computer restart did solve it for me.

PS: I think the problem is related to the checkbox on log off "Reopen windows when logging back in".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you know why this happens? This fixed my problem

Comment: I can't tell really why this happens. I just know that it happened once again since my previous message, and so I made a system update + re-installed postgresql.

I'm now running Monterey and Psql 13 and it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the fact the server is already running. We need to stop and start it.

For Mac Users:
brew services stop postgresql
brew services start postgresql

Comment: Oh man, I was freaking out there for a sec. Thank god I saw this.